# Third line clipping with padding in material designs Three-Line list

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I'm working on a java app for android where I'm displaying some info in a Three-Line list.

[Material designs guidelines for three-line lists](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-specs):
Primary text font: Roboto Regular 16sp

Secondary text font: Roboto Regular 14sp

Tile height: 88dp

Text padding, left: 16dp

Text padding, top: 16dp

Text padding, bottom: 20dp

The problem I'm having with this is that the third line clips in half, because of the bottom padding. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

This is my xml file for the list items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/listStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Test" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/listStyle"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/listStyle"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="listStyle">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">Roboto Regular</item>
</style>
```

ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
/>
```

[How the list looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYitN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change in your **LinearLayout**

```
android:layout_height="88dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Yeah that would solve the issue, but the Material Design guidelines says the tile height should be 88dp. I guess I'm just confused as to why their own guidelines would not work.